# java - Recursive combination generator running out of memory

Tags: java, combinations

I have a method to find all combinations of values from a list of lists. Currently it can causes the following error: `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`. It works fine for small sets of data, but the error occurs for larger data sets. Can someone tell how to fix my algorithm?

My code is as follows:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> generate(List<List<T>> input, BiFunction<List<T>, T, Boolean> function) {
    List<List<T>> output = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    generate(input, 0, output, null, function);
    return output;
}

private static <T> void generate(List<List<T>> input, int index, List<List<T>> output, List<T> current, BiFunction<List<T>, T, Boolean> function) {

    int next = index + 1;

    if (index == 0) {
        current = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    for (T i : input.get(index)) {
        List<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>(current);

        if (function == null || !function.apply(temp, i)) {
            temp.add(i);

            if (next >= input.size()) {
                output.add(temp);
            }
            else {
                generate(input, next, output, temp, function);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who said there's a problem with your algorithm?

Comment: Most probably your problem is in this line `List<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>(current);` since it copies the elements to new list. Any reason why `current` is not used directly without wrapping it in `temp`? Also if you are processing large data sets, it might be better to not use recursion since java has no tail call optimization and you will run into Stackoverflow errors

Comment: Have you calculated how many combinations are possible? It grows large quickly

Comment: @conscells The reason I wrapped it was because only one item should get added from each list in the input. If I don't wrap it and use `current` everywhere I currently use `temp`, all values from `input` end up in the `current` list.

Example:
If my inputs are [A, B, C], [D, E, F], [G, H, I]

Using temp I get: [A, D, G], [A, D, H], [A, D I], [A, E, G], [A, E, H] ...
Using current I get: [A, D, G, H, I, E, G, H, I, F, G, H, I, ...] 81 times

Comment: @Nayuki I could potentially have a maximum of 10^10 combinations, but more likely it will be on the order of 10^9 or less. So yes I agree, that is why I'm looking for a way to optimize.

Comment: @shmosel An `OutOfMemoryError` is somewhat of a problem, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I took better advantage of the `BiFunction` parameter to rule out more invalid combination sets at the time of creation.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try increasing your java virtual machine's memory by providing parameter -Xms. if you running from your eclipse, you can specify this in the eclipse.ini file which is present in your Eclipse home directory. you can change the parameter for example -Xms128m to -Xmx512m. Another alternative can be trying splitting the input into smaller chunks for the recursive method thereby following the mapreduce pattern.

Comment: I'd rather optimize my solution, rather than increase memory, if possible.

Comment: how about splitting the input into smaller chunks, so that the recursive method does not have to deal with too large data at a given time.This will be trade off between speed and memory. you might solve memory issue but   processing time may increase